# Editing the treeview item label using win32.

Tags: winapi

How do we edit the item's labels and setting the edit control with the modified text?

I have been doing so but the item is not being override with the new text entered.Can anyone please help me out to achieve this by using win32.

This is what I had done.

```
if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT)
            {

                hEdit=TreeView_GetEditControl(hTree);
                SetFocus(hEdit);

            }
            if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_ENDLABELEDIT)
            {

                char Text[256] = "";
                tvItem.hItem   = Selected;
                SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDC_TREE,TVM_GETITEM,0,(LPARAM)&tvItem);
                GetWindowText(hEdit, Text, sizeof(Text)); 
                tvItem.pszText = Text;
                SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDC_TREE,TVM_SETITEM,0,(LPARAM)&tvItem);


            }
```

What's the miracle you know it is showing the entered text in "tvItem.psText" ,but when I am setting the item it is not showing the item label modified and the label is same as  old text.Can anyone please help to make that edited text appears on the item label.

Thanks In Advance,
Siva V

Comment: You're going to have a real problem using `char` arrays as a string type. Windows applications for the past 15 years have been Unicode, which means `wchar_t` is the character type to use. Prefix string literals (like "") with `L`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773515.aspx), it tells you what you need to know:

> *lParam*
>  
>   Pointer to an `NMTVDISPINFO` structure. The `item` member of this structure is a `TVITEM` structure whose `hItem`, `lParam`, and `pszText` members contain valid information about the item that was edited. If label editing was canceled, the `pszText` member of the `TVITEM` structure is NULL; otherwise, `pszText` is the address of the edited text.
>
> **Return value**
>
> If the `pszText` member is non-NULL, return TRUE to set the item's label to the edited text. Return FALSE to reject the edited text and revert to the original label.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> If the `pszText` member is NULL, the return value is ignored.
>
> If you specified the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` value for this item and the `pszText` member is non-NULL, your `TVN_ENDLABELEDIT` handler should copy the text from `pszText` to your local storage.

So, try something like this:

```
...
if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT)
{
    hEdit = TreeView_GetEditControl(hTree);
    SetFocus(hEdit);
    break;
}

if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_ENDLABELEDIT)
{
    if ((LPNMTVDISPINFO)lParam)->item.pszText != NULL)
        return TRUE; // or FALSE to reject the next text...
    break;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Below the snippet to stop editing on Escape/Enter keys.

```
// Global var
WNDPROC oldWndProc;
...
// In main WindowProc, WM_NOTIFY
NMHDR* pHdr = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
if (pHdr->code == TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT) {
    HWND hEdit = TreeView_GetEditControl(hTree);
    oldWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&newWndProc);
}
...
LRESULT CALLBACK newWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
        return (DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));

    return CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code just shows you some clues.

```
LPNMHDR hdr;
NMLVDISPINFO *di;

hdr = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
di = (NMLVDISPINFO*)lParam;
...
...
switch(hdr->code)
{
...
case TVN_ENDLABELEDIT:
    if(di->tvItem.pszText != NULL)
    {
        //if you click 'Enter Key' after changing string, di->tvItem.pszText has  already changed string.
        //So, the edited string will change edit control label, by using 'return TRUE'
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        //if you cancel to edit by using 'Esc Key', di->tvItem.pszText value is NULL
        //So, the edited string will cancel, by using 'return FALSE'
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773515.aspx) states: "If the `pszText` member is NULL, the return value is ignored."  So returning FALSE is only meaningful when `pszText` is not NULL.